# Excel 2007. How can I convert names into unique IDs?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

Currently I am forming a dataset in excel. With the dataset, I am going to do the panel regression using stata(fixed effect model).
However, I cannot change people's names into their unique IDs. In my dataset, I have name in column B, and I want to generate a new column A with corresponding numbers to names in column B. Doing manually is not an option for me since the number of data is larger than 1,000. Two particular problems I encounter are that names are in Korean so the number of characters are mostly the same, and there are same people in different rows. Is there any method that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, I would do following.

**Step 1:** Used the Advanced Filter to filter on unique names

You can place these results on the same sheet or on a different sheet (as per Scott Craner's comment). Both options are listed below

*Filter Names on the same sheet*

- Select all the data in column B, then click Data > Sort & Filter > Advanced.
- Select the option to *Copy to another location*, Select a blank cell in column B location at the very bottom of your worksheet, several rows away from your data (since you won't be able to paste the results to a new sheet), and then select *Unique records only*. Then Click OK

*Filter Names on a different sheet*

- Add a new sheet and the click Data > Sort & Filter > Advanced.
- Select the option to *Copy to another location*
- Set the "List range" to the column on your dataset sheet containing the names, and Set the "Copy to" range to B1 on your new sheet
- Select *Unique records only* and then Click OK

This will paste a new range that has all the unique names in your list.

**Step 2:** Assign unique IDs to the names in the unique list

- This can easily be done by entering '1' in the Column C cell next to the first name in the unique list, '2' next to the second name, selecting those two cells, and then clicking the bottom right corner of the selected cells and dragging it down to the bottom of the unique names list

Now you have a range (i.e. unique names and IDs) that you can use `VLOOKUP` to populate an ID column in your data set

**Step 3:** Use `VLOOKUP` to populate IDs for the rows in your dataset

- For example, If your unique names and ID is in the range B1200:C1500, then you can enter the following formula in the first row of your dataset in column A (what you want to be the column with your unique IDs)

`=VLOOKUP(B2, $B$1200:$C$1500,2,0)`

After you drag this formula down your entire dataset, you'll now have the correesponding unique ID for each name.

**Step 4:** Cleanup

- Copy your column A (should be all VLOOKUP formulas) and paste Values only so you don't have the formulas there anymore
- Delete the unique data and IDs range at the bottom of sheet (or the new sheet you created to do this)

Comment: Great step by step.  One note, it is possible to copy to a different sheet when doing an advanced filter.  You just need to initiate all of it on the new sheet.  See [here](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It has been so helpful. What a clever way!

Comment: @KukdongKim  Glad you found it helpful. If it solved your problem, you could also click the check next to the answer to "accept" it. :)